# Django Rest Framework ViewSet filtering issue based on foreignkey User field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I have a django project that I am working on. There are two models in this project. There is a `user` and `account` model. I am integreating the django rest framework viewsets. I will include them below. I am now integrating the Django Rest Framework in the project. I am trying to digure out how to do two things.

2 models:

Default django user

Account Model:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    _id = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    bank_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    routing = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    _class = models.CharField(max_length=22)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=22)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    main = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    synapse = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username + ' - ' + self.name + ': ' + str(self.balance)
```

1 => I want to be able to type in the endpoint `/api/users/accounts/omarjandlai` and grab the single or many acounts with the omarjandali user foreignkey

2 => I want to be able to type into the following 
`api/users/accounts/` and return all of the accounts that are in the database

I tried 4 - 5 different ways to get this to work and I couldnt get it to work.

Here are my serializers and views

serializers:

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('user', '_id', 'name', 'balance', 'currency', 'bank_name',
                  'routing', '_class', 'type', 'active', 'main', 'synapse')
```

Views:

```
class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Account.objects.all();
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('user',)
```

what is happening is that when I do the

`api/users/account` i see all the accounts

`api/users/account/omarjandali` I get `detail not found`

urls:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet, basename='user')
router.register(r'accounts', AccountViewSet, basename='account')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Comment: Please, share your `urls.py`

Comment: I will add it to the original post at the bottom @HugoLuisVillalobosCanto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you are using **DefaultRouter**´s default functionality. That way you only can access records detail by using theirs primary key. Since you didn't specify any field as primary key explicitly (`primary=True`), **Django** sets field **id**, which is `PositiveIntegerField` as the primary key of the model. So, if you want to access the detail of a record you must use `api/users/account/112/`.

You can access records by name using filters: `api/users/account/?search='omarjandali'`, but you need to add `SearchFilter`.

```
from rest_framework.filters import SearchFilter 

class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Account.objects.all();
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter)
    filter_fields = ('user',)
    search_fields = ('name',)
```

If you want to stick to the url pattern `api/users/account/omarjandali/`, you have to add it to **urls.py** and use another viewset in order to let the original one to function accordingly to **DefaultRouter** definition:

urls.py:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet, basename='user')
router.register(r'accounts', AccountViewSet, basename='account')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api/users/account/<str:username>/', views.GetRecordsByNameViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}),
]
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework.response import Response

class GetRecordsByNameViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self, request, username):
        accounts = Account.objects.filter(user__username=username)
        accounts_to_return = AccountSerializer(accounts, many=True).data

        return Response(accounts_to_return)
```

Comment: I want to pass a `<username>` and then filter based on the user models `username field`. Would the above code do that. And if there is no username that is passed into the url, I want to get all of the accounts in the database. I want to use that parameter `username` instead of primary key...

Comment: I made some edits to address your comment. With this code you can pass <username> as a parameter and get all the records which `username` equals it. You can also get all the records in `Account` if you don't pass any `username`

Comment: Thank you, I will try it. I have been trying to solve this issue for like 2 days now. I had a differrerent stack overflow question and i was going in circles about a solution. lol

Comment: Good luck. If you want to try more complex queries for your search, check this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/search/

Comment: I wanted to use the second recomended method and I got this error `AssertionError at /api/users/account/omarjandali/
Cannot apply DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly on a view that does not set `.queryset` or have a `.get_queryset()` method.` when i trun `api/users/account/omarjandali`

Comment: I got it working properly. thank you. i had a spelling error

Comment: You're welcome. I''l appreciate you to select my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try overriding

> get_queryset (method)

With this no need to provide a username/email in URL. You would do localhost8000/accounts, it would only show accounts for the respective users.

```
class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Account.objects.all();
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('user',)

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        queryset = queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return queryset
```

Note: This will work if authentication is set in the project. In the case of token authentication, you would need to provide a token in the authorization header.